# Floating point numbers - Decimal Separator

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2009

I am trying to write to an xml file but I am having difficulties handling Floating point numbers as they are using a comma(,) as decimal separator even though my regional settings are set to be a dot(.) for a decimal separator. I am having this problem in Windows Server 2012, but in Windows XP I am not experiencing this.

```
 GetLocaleFormatSettings(GetThreadLocale, LocalFormatSettings);
   LocalFormatSettings.DecimalSeparator := '.';

   SHElem := xml.Root.Items.Add('SalesHeader');
   with SHElem do begin
    Items.Add('STORENUMBER', ssCurrentStoreNumber);
      case VarType(Dataset.FieldByName('Amounts').asFloat) of
      varCurrency : Items.Add('Amounts', FloatToStr(Dataset.FieldByName('Amount').asFloat,LocalFormatSettings));
      else          
      Items.Add('Fields', Dataset.FieldByName('Fields').AsString);
      end
   end;
```

Comment: How do you write your floating point numbers to the XML file? Please show the relevant piece of code.

Comment: If it is a $/cent value, and you have control of both the reader and the writer, you could let the field be expressed in cents instead of $ (ie. multiply the value by 100 to get an integer to store in the XML and then divide it by 100 on the receiving end). That way you are independent on the actual decimal seperator (since there is none).

Comment: If you are using the Delphi `TXMLDocument` for writing, you may have to write floats as a string and use the method described by @DavidHeffernan. Note that dates/times also needs special treatments, since Delphi does not follow the XML-scheme standards in `TXMLDocument`.

Comment: You can use *VAL* and *STR* procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a format settings object when converting from a float to a string. For instance:

```
var
  fs: TFormatSettings;
....
GetLocaleFormatSettings(GetThreadLocale, fs);
fs.DecimalSeparator := '.';
```

Then when you convert, do so like this, for instance:

```
str := FloatToStr(Value, fs);
```

Comment: I have tried to do this, but it seems my application is ignoring my variable.

Comment: You've not provided any code, and so you cannot expect any detailed help relating to your code. Fundamentally the problem here is that you need to improve your question. Prepare a small MCVE and add that in an edit to the question.

Comment: That code is really hard to read. You need to introduce some local variables to make the lines shorter and so stop repeating yourself. Are you saying that the code in my answer does not work?

Comment: It works when I execute it. I suggest that you make an MCVE. You'll strip out all the database code because that's not needed to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: I cannot execute your code. Surely you can make an MCVE. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: thanks David, its working now, somehow I just had to call the DecimalSeparator directly from Sysutils without creating a variable as this gets ignored.

Comment: @Fero68 I don't actually believe that is the case. I suspect that your code differs from what you have shown. When you run the code in my answer you will find that it behaves as expected.

Comment: i think maybe its versions which differ,I tried your answer in Delphi XE5, and it works perfectly by using a local variable, but in Delphi 2009 this behaves differently as I need to call the DecimalSeparator directly (like this DecimalSeparator := '.') , using the global variable declared in SysUtils unit

Comment: I find that a little hard to believe.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to put into the project file UpdateFormatSettings property to false, to prevent all changes by the SO or other applications like ms Excel and so on.

```
{$R *.res}
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.UpdateFormatSettings:=False;
  ......
  Application.Run;
end.
```

after that, you have to put the fololowing code in the fisrst form you create.

```
 FormatSettings.decimalseparator:='.';

 // you can find other interestin settings like this:
 FormatSettings.TimeSeparator:=':';
 FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat:='dd/MM/yyyy';
 FormatSettings.ShortTimeFormat:='hh:mm:ss';
 FormatSettings.LongTimeFormat:='hh:mm:ss';
```

The code above is usend on XE7.
In Delphi 6/7 you have to change the code in this way:

```
  //this one is the same
  Application.UpdateFormatSettings := false;
```

for regional settings you can write this:

```
decimalseparator:='.';
TimeSeparator:=':';
ShortDateFormat:='dd/MM/yyyy';
ShortTimeFormat:='hh:mm:ss';
LongTimeFormat:='hh:mm:ss';
```

In Delphi 2009 you can use the global variable DecimalSeparator (declared in SysUtils unit) e.g. DecimalSeparator:= '.'

Comment: Question is tagged Delphi 2009, so we do know which version is being used